# Как компактно конвертировать строку в массив целочисленных значений?

Tags: c#, массивы, строки, числа

Знаю, что можно это сделать циклом, но мне нужен способ для которого не придётся писать его блок кода. Нужен самый компактный вариант записи.

```
string s = "23 43 65 2323 66";
int[] ints =  // {23, 43, 65, 2323, 66};
```

Comment: "Быстро" или "Компактно"? Это две совершенно разные вещи... Вот вам максимально "компактно" `int[] ints = s.Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();`, ну а "быстро" компактно не получится)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну а чем этот способ не быстрый, он во всех смыслах оптимальный вполне )

Comment: @CrazyElf, ну не, сначала сплит, потом Parse, а потом еще новый массив.

Comment: @Grundy Так и что? Насколько я понимаю это как генератор "лениво" будет работать, а не так, чтобы под каждый этап полностью под все данные память будет выделяться.

Comment: @CrazyElf, не,`Split` - не ленивый метод, он всегда создает массив, Select ленивый - и создает новый итератор, ToArray - не ленивый - проходит **всему** итератору и создает новый массив

Comment: @CrazyElf В моем  примере есть два проблемных места, а именно, как сказали выше, `Split()` и `.ToArray()`, это весьма медленные и затратные по ресурсам методы, от которых можно избавиться вовсе или очень сильно оптимизировать, решив задачу в 2 раза быстрее, и даже без аллокаций. Допустим, можем реализовать `Split()`, который будет основан на `Span` ([пример](https://www.meziantou.net/split-a-string-into-lines-without-allocation.htm)), а от `ToArray()` отказаться вовсе. Тут все зависит от задачи, потребностей, зачастую такая сильная оптимизация не нужна, достаточно того, что я дал выше.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну вот именно, что преждевременная оптимизация - зло. Сначала нужно померить, действительно ли тут что-то куда-то упирается, или никому это не важно )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
int[] ints = Array.ConvertAll(s.Split(), int.Parse);
```

А вот с циклом, но без блока кода, и без промежуточного массива :-)

```
var l = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0, j, k; (j = i) < s.Length; l.Add(int.Parse(s.Substring(j, (i = (k = s.IndexOf(" ", i)) < 0 ? s.Length : k + 1) - j))));
```